# How can I detect my phone's screen resolution?

Tags: screen-resolution

Other than looking in the Chinese manufacturer's website, which can be somewhat "misleading" (12.1 MP camera? come on...)

Answer (score 29):

You can visit [whatismyandroidversion.com](http://whatismyandroidversion.com) from your phone's web browser which will show you your screen resolution, android version and device id.

Comment: Neat way to get it on most/all devices. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Since I was not entirely sure if the system information was correct, I simply checked the resolution of a **screenshot** from my phone. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `Settings > About phone > Hardware information > Display`

E.g. on my phone, it says "3.7 inch WVGA resolution"

(Then of course, you would have to discover what WVGA is...)

The Hardware information screen should also tell you the camera specs too.

Comment: no "Hardware information" in about phone section for me :(

Comment: what device are you using? I am running vanilla Android (CyanogenMOD7) on a Vibrant and I don't have that option either.

Comment: Ah, that'll be HTC Sense only. Sorry, we HTC users tend to occupy a parallel universe sometimes.

Comment: I've tried running (stock) Froyo and Gingerbread on the Android emulator which comes with the SDK, and I can't find any UI that tells you the screen or camera resolution. So an external app or manufacturer customization is the only way.

Answer (score -1):

if you follow much the same path that Nick suggested, but instead go to `Settings > Display > Display Resolution` it should show you the options for your screen resolution.

As for your photos, take a picture, put it on your computer and check the resolution. And let us know if you actually have a 12.1 MP camera!! :)

Comment: what device do you have? again, on stock android 2.3.4 that is not an option.

Comment: woops! i have an HTC EVO on 2.2 still, which has hd resolution, and mine gives you options of `Automatic`, `720p (1280x720)`, and `480p (720x480)`. Apparently that's a phone specific option? Have you tried running [Quadrant Standard](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quadrant-standard-edition/com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard)? it gives you feedback about all system information (including display resolution!!)

Comment: cant believe i forgot to suggest that app the first time. sorry!